# How does Date.getHours() works

Tags: javascript

I can not clearly understand how does `Date.getHours` works. I live in montenegro and for me GMT is `+2`. I checked it in google and in browser console

```
new Date() // Date Tue Aug 02 2022 15:26:32 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

```js
const date1 = new Date('December 31, 1975, 16:00:00 GMT+04:00');
const date2 = new Date('December 31, 1975, 16:00:00 GMT-04:00');
const date3 = new Date('December 31, 1975, 16:00:00 GMT+00:00');

console.log(date1.getUTCHours()); // 12
console.log(date2.getUTCHours()); // 20
console.log(date3.getUTCHours()); // 16

console.log('-------------------------')

console.log(date1.getHours()); // 13
console.log(date2.getHours()); // 21
console.log(date3.getHours()); // 17
```

UTC hours is I understand clearly plus/minus 4 hours and 0 hours. But why I get odd numbers when get non UTC hours?

1. I expected to get 14 in first logs because the time was in GMT+4, my timezone is GMT+2, so difference is 2 not 3
2. With same logic I expected to see 22, because difference is -6
3. And 18 in third log because difference is -2

Comment: Are you sure that in 1975 the timezone rules were the same as now? Timezone rules sometimes change, and JavaScript takes the historical rules into account.

Comment: Some UTC time zone have different hours betweens summer and winter. It might come from here I think

Comment: See https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/montenegro and https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/montenegro . In winter Montenegro is only 1 hour ahead of GMT/UTC. Test it again with a summer date and see if you get different results.

Comment: @Jesper I didn't check it, I just get example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours#try_it) and change clock

Comment: @ADyson Oh damn summer and winter time, thank you very much!

Comment: @Ivar on the date specified in the code, it would have been. local time in that country changes according to the time of year - see the links I posted.

Comment: Thank you all guys, you saved my day! The question can be closed

Comment: @EzioMercer no problem. It's always something to try and remember. Times, dates, timezones etc are a programmer's nightmare. P.S. You can probably just delete the question as there is no real value to others in it.